# time picker in php

Tags: php, javascript

please help me out regarding time in php. I want to make time selection for a website that offers their services at different time . I want to make it like a date picker calendar . I haven't find anything yet . i can make in drop down box but showing the 60 min drop down looks quite ugly . plz help me out regarding this .

Comment: If you didnt find one by [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=timepicker), you didnt try hard enough.

Comment: First search result on Google when searching for Javascript timepicker: [21 Free Javascript Timepicker](http://www.bitrepository.com/a-collection-of-free-javascript-date-pickers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML5, it natively supports date pickers and all time-related inputs. See http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html

Comment: so when I use HTML5 the IE6 I am forced to use at work will show a datepicker? kewl!

Comment: Or any current browser for that matter. Giving that kind of advice without propper context seems dangerous to me. That doesn't even work in 95% of the browsers used today does it?

Comment: Actually, there's a proper notice on page I've suggested (sorry, I probably should have included it in my answer). There's also hint what to do if browser doesn't support HTML5. Though using HTML5 is now not that popular and somehow risky, it's the only way to force environment to support it.

Answer (score 3):

Well I won't recommend you making it from scratch. Instead you can use the jquery plugins available freely :). Some of them I recommend are

**1) Full Calendar**

> FullCalendar is a famous jQuery
> calendar plugin which offers features
> like drag-and-drop, integration with
> Google Calendar and able to fetch
> events through JSON. Designers can
> easily customize the look and feel of
> the calendar, while developers can
> utilize the exposed hooks for
> user-triggered events.
>
> **Website: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/**

**2) jQuery Interactive Date Range Picker**

> This powerful date range picker is a
> modified version of jQuery UI’s
> Datepicker component. It has a quicker
> date selection from a list of preset
> dates/ranges and a smooth transitions.
> The latest version uses the jQuery UI
> 1.7 and jQuery UI CSS Framework. With the power of jQuery UI, user can now
> switch the calendar theme easily.

Answer (score 2):

You might like my jQuery UI timepicker plugin. I built it to looks like the jQuery datepicker.

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker